# How to exclude vertices from subdivison modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]
I'd like to have the subdivision modifier connect those 3 points and not interpolate between them. This question is the opposite of this question: [How to include vertices to subdivision modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131997/how-to-include-vertices-to-subdivision-modifier/132023#132023)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't exactly exclude the vertices rather you can tell the subdivision modifier to not affect some vertices. To do that follow the steps

1. Select the vertices you need to exclude
2. Press Shift + E
3. Drag your mouse up to set the crease to the value of 1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** After all, it doesn't work as it first seemed because it creates new vertices that then cause problems.

I've found it: The option "Edge Split" does exactly that:
[image]

After applying:
[image]