# I have some weird shading issues

Tags: mesh, shaders, edges, lighting

I'm kinda new in blender so I'm trying to improove by making some low poly characters. But as you can see, I've got some weird shading issues. I have no clue how to fix this. And before you suggest me changing lighning or so - I want it to look cartoonish.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You could try selcting the whole mesh in edit mode (with "a") and then shift+N. That fixes the normals in some cases. I had about the same issue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131997/how-to-include-vertices-to-subdivision-modifier

Comment: Or use Ctrl+N if you are using Blender 2.79, Shift+N is shortcut for blender 2.8

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I wish i could give you thumbs up or so.